# openSuse installation trouble

Tags: opensuse-11.2

yesterday my collegue did a mistake. She has been lauched the openSuse installer from a running Windows 7 notebook. Now, when the notebook boot, appear the installer linuxrc taht try to install the openSuse OS.

Currently we are not able to run Windows 7. How can we go back to the original situation?

Comment: the open suse has not any rescue mode
you should use ubuntu or other ditro

Answer (score 1):

If the install process was interrupted at the beginning and no partitions were destroyed (aka your Win7 is still there) just boot from any linux disk, choose to enter in a rescue mode and restore windows boot loader. I described this process this way because it's generic, but the options may be called differently from distribution to distribution.

In Mandriva Linux, at boot time from disk you can press F2, write 'rescue', a menu appears and select 'rescue system', then 'restore windows boot loader'

I don't know the exact Suse menu for this, but you should be able to find something similar.